# И снова о Кощее

Tags: фольклор, этимология

Почитал интересные ответы на вопрос о Кощее Бессмертном и увидел там любопытное замечание по поводу того, что слово "Кощей" может означать не излишне костлявое существо, а пленника, и слово это тюркского происхождения.
Тогда очень интересно было бы узнать, кто подразумевается под персонажем русского фольклора, который, судя по сказкам, не только не является ничьим пленником, а и сам очень даже успешно берет в плен всяких Василис Премудрых и Прекрасных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу происхождения Кощея существует много версий, например:

1) Слово «кощей» в XII веке означало раба, пленника; в Слове о полку Игореве термин упомянут дважды: Игорь, попав в плен к Кончаку, садится «в седло кощеево» Это слово, по наиболее распространённой этимологии, от тюркского kоšči «невольник» , которое, в свою очередь, образовано от kоš «лагерь, стоянка» (в древнерусском «кошь» — стан, обоз.

2) Кощей, как имя героя сказки и как обозначение тощего человека, Макс Фасмер в своём словаре считает не тюркизмом, а исконно славянским словом (омонимом) и связывает со словом кость. Кроме того, в старославянском языке слово "кощь" (или "кошть") обозначает "тощий", "сухой" или "худой". Все мы помним внешний облик нашего антигероя: кожа да кости.

3) Происхождение имени этого сказочного персонажа имеет филологический характер: созвучие и общая семантика с некоторыми словами, например, с кощунством. "Кощун" - это колдун. И действительно: бессмертны только всемогущие черные маги, а также люди, обратившиеся за помощью к темным силам (например, Фауст Гете).

4) Толковый словарь В.И.Даля определяет слово «кощейничать» в значении «скряжничать, жадничать, жидомордничать...» Как тут не вспомнить великого Пушкина: «Там царь Кощей над златом чахнет»!

5) Следует обратить внимание и на то, где именно спрятана смерть Кощея. То есть на древнейший символ жизни, вселенной - яйцо, снесенное птицей. Здесь явно прослеживается древнейший мифологический мотив о Змее, хранившим мировое Яйцо, и пребывавшем в хаосе. После того, как его убивает самый первый культурный герой, хаосу приходит конец и начинает формироваться космос, подчиненный всем законам мироздания.

Comment: Связь имени "кощей" с яйцом не понятна  
"кощейничать" - производное от "кощей".  
"кощун" - "сказитель". Значение "колдун" появилось уже в христианстве.  
Ну, и, наконец "кощь" пришло в старославянский из булгарского, который "замусорен" тюркизмами.

Answer (score 2):

В сказках подразумевается тот самый Кощей - злой колдун, часто выступающий в роли похитителя невесты главного героя.
Однако и ваше приведенное значение имеет место. Но это слово в этом значении (согласно Википедии) устаревшее. Кроме имени героя сказок, слово имеет ещё два устаревших значения: "худой (или скупой) человек" и, в древнерусских текстах, "пленник". .... " Во многих сказках упоминается, что Кощей является пленником, триста лет пробывшим в заточении либо в башне либо подземелье, скованным цепями". [Википедия. Кощей Бессмертный](http://www.quickiwiki.com/ru/%CA%EE%F9%E5%E9)